# Genetic Algorithm for maximization

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, genetic-algorithms

this may be a shot in the dark, but I am trying to teach myself more machine learning concepts. I have found a textbook and am trying to work through the exercises in it. Could anyone help me with this example?

Example:

Use genetic algorithm to solve the following optimization problem, including the initialize population, fitness function and each iteration until you find the optimal solution.

```
max f(x1, x1) = 2x(1)^2 + x(2)^2 + 3x(3)^2


s.t.     x1 ∈{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
         x2 ∈{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
         x3 ∈{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Any information that anyone could give me or even resources that work through examples like this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? What resources have you read, to learn about this topic, and what are your thoughts on possible approaches? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.